# Selecting opportunity contact role on related contact account

Tags: administration, related-list, opportunitycontactrole, accountcontactrelation

Part of our process before an opportunity is closed won, we need to create contact roles, until now if a contact is related to 2 different companies we create both accounts and we duplicate the contact, this way we can select them as 2 different contact roles.

I have activated the Related contacts for the account, this way I can add the same contact to 2 different accounts without having to duplicate this contact, this works perfect, however I am unable to select the second account when creating contact roles.

I am wondering if there is a setting that I need to activate to be able to select the other account, for example the image below, the contact named fab man is related to companies dummy 1 and dummy 2, but the only option that I have in the list is the contact from dummy 2 as this is the one marked as direct

[image]

In case some one is wondering why this? From the contact roles we generate a PDF and we need to bring the account name into the document

Answer (score 0):

I have created 2 accounts "dummy 1" and "dummy 2" and created a direct contact "test contact" under "dummy 2"

[image]

I have then related this "test contact" to "dummy 1" account in "contact roles" related list.

[image]

I have then created an opportunity "test opportunity" related to "dummy 1" account. I have added contact role under opportunity.

[image]

The "test contact" contact is showing up in the contact roles creation page of the opportunity without any additional settings.
[image]

Have you done anything different? Please let me know.

Comment: Hi thank you for the detail description, it is slightly different what I am trying to do, so far what you have done is very similar to what I have done, the issue is that the opportunity needs to have 2 contact roles, not 1, and I want to avoid creating the same duplicate contact under dummy 1, for this you will need to activate the multiple related contacts, so the end goal is to have in the opportunity, 2 contact roles: test contact from dummy 1 as role 1 and test contact from dummy 2 as role 2

Comment: I have activated multiple related contacts and I am adding the related contact of an account to create contact role on that account.

Comment: what I am trying is to do is to add the 2 contact role into the opportunity, but 1 contact role is for dumy 1 and the scond contact role is for dumy 2, unfortunately for me i can only pick the one for dummy 2 thatis where the direct relation ship is at

Comment: You will only be able to add those contact roles on an opportunity which are added as related contact on the opportunity's parent account. So add both the contacts as related contact on the account and then create an opportunity on that account. You should be able to add both the contacts as contact roles under the opportunity.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding you, but that is what i did in the first place

Comment: Maybe you don't have access to the other contact hence you won't be able to add it as a contact role on the opportunity.

Comment: Im the system admin, the image i add, i created both accounts contact and opp, could you add the image of your current roles please? Perhaps i havent explain myself correctly

Comment: I don't have any roles assigned.